# MongoDB aggregate lookup another collection by custom match

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have 2 collections.
First collection includes this field: 
COLLECTION 1:

```
{
    phone: '123456'
}
```

PHONECALLS:

```
{
    ...
    number: '+123456'
}
```

By aggregating the first collection, I want to get all the documents from the Phonecalls collection by matching the numbers.

Required result:

```
{
    phone: '123456',
    phonecalls: [
        {...}
        {...}
        {...}
    ]
}
```

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you think you mean by "aggregating"? All I see here is returning a list of matching entries, and that is **not** "aggregating". The data presented does not appear to match ( by a `+` prepended to one item ) and it's not clear if that is your actual format or even "why?" there should be a difference. The usual practice when you want to "join" is to make the data the same so the keys actually match. But the whole question is really abstract and could do with some clarification.

Comment: By aggregation I mean use the aggregation query and not just the 'find'

Comment: Try and be specific about your data. Why are the values different in each collection? Why do they **need** to be different? Would it simply not make more sense to make both values `123456` instead of having one prefixed? You are actually being asked to write a clearer question, as well as think through it logically. You also should post a realistic sample of what you really need to do. Abstract questions get abstract answers, and often the answer does not suit your real needs. This wastes everyones time and most importantly does not help to solve your problem.